# WCF web services, JSON and Membership/Roles issue

Tags: wcf, json, asp.net-membership, wcf-binding, wcf-security

We write a WCF web service. 
How can we call it's methods in JSON format?
An additional issue is how can we secure our web services.
I'd like to use Microsoft Membership and Roles providers for users authentication and authorization. The question is how to do this. Is it possible to do authentication and authorization behind-the-scenes (in context of WCF), or I must call ValidateUser() and IsUserInRole() in every web method for every user call?
Whether I restricted to use webHttpBinding (over wsHttpBinding) because our client-side programmer familiar with AJAX/JSON? Whether there are any restrictions of webHttpBinding concerning using Membership/Roles comparably comparably to wsHttpBinding?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Ilan.

Comment: How did you write web services? Do you already have them prepared for REST calls = `WebGet`, `WebInvoke` attributes? The first part of your question looks more like searching for tutorial.

Comment: No I didn't prepare them for REST.. Could you recommend some tutorial?